# Log Y axis in barplot with values smaller than 1 and including plot lines with negative values

Tags: r, logging, bar-chart, axis

I have plotted a bar graph with values smaller than 1 and combined it with two lines, one with positive and the other with negative larger values. When I plot it, the bar lines are much smaller and difficult to see. I would like to change the scale of the Y axis so that the bars that go from 0 to 0.5 are seen bigger. The objective would be to try to break the y axis in 2, from 0 to 0.5 and the rest. I thought about applying log = "y" to barplot, but the axis goes from negative to positive and cannot be logged. (Error in barplot.default(data$bv, data$year, ylim = c(-3, 3), log = "y") : log scale error: at least one 'height + offset' value <= 0 ). Any ideas about how to solve this?

```
    data <- data.frame(c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018))
data$bv <- as.numeric(c(0.29,-0.15,0.1, 0.3, 0.2, -0.1, 0.25, -0.2, -0.3,0.08,-0.54, -0.24, -0.15, 0.26, 0.12, 0.23,-0.16,0.3))
data$pvp <- as.numeric(rep(c(2.8,2.9,3),times=6))
data$pvn <- as.numeric(rep(c(-2.8,-2.9,-3),times=6))
data$year <- as.numeric(c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018))
bar <- barplot(data$bv, data$year, ylim=c(-3,3))
par(new = T)
plot(data$pvp,ylim=c(-3,3),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="b",lty=3,lwd=1.5,pch=15,cex=0.8)
points(data$pvn,type="b",lty=3,lwd=1.5,pch=17,cex=0.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the log of the absolute value, then multiply that by the sign of the original value:

```
data$bv <- log(abs(data$bv)) * sign(data$bv)
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan, this can be a partial solution to the issue. However, I would prefer to maintain the values of the bars and instead log the Y axis.